# Deleting files with long name in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, windows, delete-file

I have an old application which is running on .Net Framework. Facing errors while deleting files with long name:

- More than 260 characters, no spaces but includes diacritics.
- Files are located in a server, hence the path looks like "//127.0.0.1/shared-path/path/file".
- Error says "Could not find part of the path".
- Problematic files can be deleted manually going to that folder.
- Files were created by .Net Framework application.

All following codes failed to deleted the files:

```
// "file" w/ long name located in "directory"

File.Delete(Path.Combine(@"\\?\UNC\", directory, file));

File.Delete(Path.Combine(@"\\?\", directory, file));

File.Delete(Path.Combine(@"\\.\", directory, file));
```

Comment: I would refactor your code to have the result of Path.Combine set to a local variable and then have a look at whether the value of the variable is the path that you're expecting

Comment: I already checked the logs and path are as expected.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the loopback to the same server, so why don't you just use the `C:\` or whatever exact local path?

Comment: Actually its some ip address of a storage server where these files are located. `127.0.0.1`  in this case is just a placeholder.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use combine, use a single string where you combine everything.
I tried it with combine and had the same error than you.

```
string directory = @"\temp\";
string file = "example.txt";
File.Delete($"C:{directory}{file}");
```

Comment: combine is a frequently used utility.  It is also OS-independent.  Building your own would cause problems.  For exam path=$"{dir}\\filename" would work on Windows but fail on Mac or Linux.